# Check if TCP client connection failed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tcp, tcpclient

I'm trying to send a message from one application to another, here's my code for the sender

```
Try
    Client = New TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8000)
    Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
    Writer.Write("</> " & TextBox1.Text & " <\>")
    Writer.Flush()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

This code works fine because i'm just using the localhost ip address, but if I input some other ip address that will obviously not reply, the program throws a connect failed error, or sometimes an error saying the target actively refused the connetion.

How can i do something like `If clientconnection = success then...` instead of getting an exception thrown

Comment: Does the `on error goto <label>` functionality exist in vb.net? I know in quickbasic and visual basic it does. Then at `<label>:` process the custom error code.

Answer (score 0):

TcpClient has a Connected boolean property.
Check this before you call GetStream.

[MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT: But you should still continue exception handling as the connection could drop at any point anyway.

Comment: Actually, I failed to mention that the exception is thrown on `Client = New TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 8000)` this line.

Comment: Hmm Ok... just declare the TcpClient first and use the default constructor, and the call client.Connect(ip, port). Then you can wrap this Connect call in its own exception handling.